# Python Pattern Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a input text as follows:

```
 SAVE_TIMECARD = "insert into sh_user_timecard (instance_id, user_id, in_time, in_time_activity_log_aid, in_time_activity_log_instance_id, " +"out_time, out_time_activity_log_aid, out_time_activity_log_instance_id, parent_aid, parent_instance_id)" + " values (:instanceId, :userId, :inTime, :inTimeActivityAid, :inTimeActivityInstanceId, :outTime, :outTimeActivityAid, " +":outTimeActivityInstanceId, :parentAid, :parentInstanceId)";
```

The output I need is:

```
 SAVE_TIMECARD  =:instanceId, :userId, :inTime, :inTimeActivityAid, :inTimeActivityInstanceId, :outTime, :outTimeActivityAid, " +":outTimeActivityInstanceId, :parentAid, :parentInstanceId
```

I've tried achieving this using:

```
result = re.findall(r'[A-z]+(:?=)',inputfile)
```

I need to extract the upper case words that is SAVE_TIMECARD  and allthe words that starts with colon.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Show us the code, so we can help you on a specific error.

Comment: result = re.findall(r'\[A-z]+(:?=)',inputfile)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

import re
regex = re.compile("^[^=]{0,}|:(\w{1,})")

testString = "private static final String SAVE_TIMECARD = "insert into sh_user_timecard (instance_id, user_id, in_time, in_time_activity_log_aid, in_time_activity_log_instance_id, " +"out_time, out_time_activity_log_aid, out_time_activity_log_instance_id, parent_aid, parent_instance_id)" + " values (:instanceId, :userId, :inTime, :inTimeActivityAid, :inTimeActivityInstanceId, :outTime, :outTimeActivityAid, " +":outTimeActivityInstanceId, :parentAid, :parentInstanceId)";"

matchArray = regex.findall(testString)

## the matchArray variable contains the list of matches

Answer (score 0):

```
:\w+
```

Will identify the 'words starting with a colon'. You'll need to loop through the original text to find all instances.